# Randomly selecting from previous randomly selected elements from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

First, i created an array of, let`s say, 6 elements. Then i randomly pick 4 elements that are GOOD (on random position i mean).

Now, i want to randomly pick 2 out of those 4 selected that are VERY GOOD.
If the value of array1 is the same with array2, then i want it to say VERY GOOD. Else, say GOOD. If the value is 0, then BAD.

I tried allpossibilities and all failed.

This is my last attempt of doing so...

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
while (count($array1) < 4) {
    $rand = rand(1,6);
    if (!isset($array1[$rand])) {
         $array1[$rand] = TRUE;

    }
}

while (count($array2) < 2) {
    $rand = rand(1,4);
    if (!isset($array2[$rand])) {
        $array2[$rand] = TRUE;


    }
}


$array2 = $array2 + array_fill(1, 4, FALSE);
$array1 = $array1 + array_fill(1, 6, FALSE);

ksort($array1);
ksort($array2);

foreach($array1 as $k => $v){
    if ($v != 0)
{echo "GOOD<br>";}
else {echo "BAD<br>";}}
foreach($array2 as $kc => $vc){
    if ($v2 !=0)
{echo "VERY GOOD<br>";}
else {echo "BAD<br>";}}
```

This is what it gives me:

```
GOOD
GOOD
BAD
GOOD
GOOD
BAD
VERY GOOD
BAD
BAD
VERY GOOD
```

As you can see, it gave me 4/6 GOODS and then 2/6 VERY GOODS.
What i wanted was 4/6 GOODS and from those 4 selected i want 2/4 VERY GOODS.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance,
Vlad

Comment: `$array = $array + array_fill(1, 6, FALSE);`? Maybe `$array1` should be here?

Comment: Sorry, i misstyped it here. It has $array1 in the code...

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/DYmgyoiL), 4/6 and 2/4

Comment: What do you mean by "Cannot reproduce"?

Comment: When I used your code and formatted it a bit, I realized that I get 4/6 goods and 2/4 very goods, so what is the problem?

Comment: I want 4/6 and, from those 4 i want 2. Basically, i want GOOD, GOOD, VERY GOOD, VERY GOOD, BAD, BAD. There is a maximum of 6 possibilities. 4 are GOOD and from those 4 2 are VERY GOOD. The rest is BAD. If you see the output, you don`t have 6 iterations, you have 10, meaning the code is adding up the 6 chances for GOOD and the 4 chances for VERY GOOD.

Comment: That makes sense ;) But since those are separated in code as `$array1` and `$array2` which have the sizes 6 and 4 what makes you think they magically merge?

Comment: So i should merge the two arrays THEN run the code to get what i want? Where should i put the merge command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want one array of size 6 so why are you creating multiple? You can either merge them in some fashion or use the first in construction of the second.

But first, I want to point out that the `while()` loops are very similar, so it should be easy to put that into a `function` and save some code to write and have a codebase that is better manageable, as you only need to edit one place to have immediate effect instead of many.

Now for the first task, all you need is the `$num`ber of elements to be created and the `$range`. This function will do what one of your `while()` loops did plus the `array_fill()`. ([demo](http://codepad.org/Vt3fFH3w))

```
function fillRandom($range, $num = 1) {
    $data = array_fill($range[0], $range[1]+1, FALSE);

    for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) {
        do {
            $key = mt_rand($range[0], $range[1]);
        } while ($data[$key] === TRUE);
        $data[$key] = TRUE;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Now comes the more advanced part: In the second run, we can identify 2 out of the 4 `TRUE` in the array of 6 elements by giving them another `$value` (as an example).

The `$data` will be needed in some cases and by using an [`$anon`ymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) we can allow the condition for the `while()` to be passed.

```
function fillRandom($range, $num = 1, $value = TRUE, $data = array(), $anon = NULL) {
    if (empty($data))
        $data = array_fill($range[0], $range[1]+1, FALSE);
    if ($anon === NULL) {
        $anon = function($el) use($value) {
            return $el !== $value;
        };
    }

    for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) {
        do {
            $key = mt_rand($range[0], $range[1]);
        } while (isSet($data[$key]) && !$anon($data[$key]));
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You can then do something like this ([demo](http://3v4l.org/BYX8q))

```
$input = fillRandom(array(0, 5), 4);

ksort($input);
print_r($input);

$input = fillRandom(array(0, 5), 2, 2, $input, function($el){
    return $el === TRUE;
});

ksort($input);
print_r($input);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what i wanted! God bless you, sir!